# How to show exasperation?

Tags: expressions

If I were to write "aiyaa, 这是太贵了!“

Wondering how to show exasperation in writing? Or how to write the aiyaa?

Comment: Āiyā is 哎呀 :) .

Comment: FYI, in Cantonese it is 哎吔.

Answer (score 2):

You can just say 哎呀，太贵了！ to express the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

汗 is also an awesome nonvocal way to express exasperation in written Chinese.

CC-CEDICT:

> 3 to be speechless (out of helplessness, embarrassment etc) (Internet slang used as an interjection)

You could totally write: "汗, 太贵了!"

Answer (score 0):

哎呀!

Is how you write Āiyā! in Chinese.